# How to set an enum that I can use throughout my app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an enum class as follows:

```
namespace Import.DataObjects
{
    internal enum EmploymentStatus
    {
        FullTime,
        Terminated,    
    }
}
```

As of right now I am calling a method in Main to set this enum. The problem is, when I am done setting the enum and the method that sets it ends, the enum is blank again. How do I retain the values in the enum throughout the app using this method?

Comment: Please include more code. Where the instance of the enum is declared and how you're setting it at a minimum.

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting, you mean you're assigning an enum value to a variable and it's losing its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enum-typed variables don't magically change their values.  Here's an example of how to use them.

```
class Foo {
    private EmploymentStatus Status;

    void Operation() {
        this.Status = EmploymentStatus.FullTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enums are usually final. An ENUMs are typically used for cases like

```
enum DAYS_OF_WEEK
{
 SUNDAY=1
 MONDAY=2
 ...
}
```

or

```
   enum ERROR_CODES
   {
     BAD_ACCESS = 0xBADACE55
   }
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx for usage examples

usualy its not suggested to mutate them as you propose.

What it sounds like you are after is a singleton or some kind of static configuration object.